# How to get a list of calculated metrics from Google Analytics REST API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

This feature is still in beta but nevertheless is there any resource available with more information how to retrieve this list?

Comment: Depends on which version of the api you want to use and which language.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns&jump=ga_calcmetric_<name>  is just a metric that you request.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

Comment: Unfortunately your question is to broad I have voted it be closed.  please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the answer.

I know how to retrieve the value for actual metric. So your links were not helpful.

But to retrieve the value of the metric you also need the external name of the calculated metric. For example, you can get this external name from Google Analytics UI if you go to the list of the calculated metrics.

What I'm interested in is how to get this list by using API. I did ask in the title of the question "get a list ..." :)

Comment: The management API has a list of custom metrics but I am not sure that calculated metrics were part of that.  I remember the team speaking about adding it.  However i cant seem to find an issue request for it https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customMetrics

Comment: try https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customMetrics/list if you don't get any back add a feature request here https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list post the request link in a comment and I will start it with you and take it up with the team next time I speak with them.

Comment: Thank you @DaImTo. Here is the link to the issue: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=1132

Comment: I will add it to my list of things to bring up with the team next time I meet with them.  Probably wont be until after the new year though.